# Printing variable from Python function having nested for loops

Tags: python, output

How can I print `Stot` in the following code? That's really all I want.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint

A = np.logspace(-2, 2, 5, 10)
lenA = len(A)
B = 2*np.logspace(-4, 1, 6, 10)
lenB = len(B)

S0plot = np.zeros((lenA,lenB))
S1plot = np.zeros((lenA,lenB))
KS0plot = np.zeros((lenA,lenB))
PS1plot = np.zeros((lenA,lenB))
Kplot = np.zeros((lenA,lenB))
Pplot = np.zeros((lenA,lenB))
y0 = [0] * 6
ydot = np.zeros((6,1))

def f(y):
    for Bloop in range(lenB):
        for Aloop in range(lenA):
            A0 = A[Aloop]
            Q = B[Bloop]
            r1 = 2e-5
            r2 = 2e-4
            a = 0.001
            d = 0.001
            k = 0.999
            P0 = 1
            tf = 1e10
            time = np.linspace(0, tf, 1001)
            S00 = Q/r1

            S0 = y[0]
            S1 = y[1]
            KS0 = y[2]
            PS1 = y[3]
            K = y[4]
            P = y[5]

            ydot[0] = Q-r1*S0+d*KS0-a*K*S0+k*PS1
            ydot[1] = k*KS0+d*PS1-S1*(r1+a*K+a*P)
            ydot[2] = a*K*S0-(d+k+r1)*KS0
            ydot[3] = a*P*S1-(d+k+r1)*PS1
            ydot[4] = (d+k+r1)*(KS0)-a*K*(S0+S1)
            ydot[5] = (d+k+r2)*PS1-a*P*S1       

            return ydot[:,0]

            y0[0] = S00
            y0[1] = 0
            y0[2] = 0
            y0[3] = 0
            y0[4] = A0
            y0[5] = P0

            soln = odeint(f, y0, time, mxstep = 5000)        
            S0 = soln[:,0]
            S1 = soln[:,1]
            KS0 = soln[:,2]
            PS1 = soln[:,3]
            K = soln[:,4]
            P = soln[:,5]
            S0plot[Aloop,Bloop] = soln[len(time)-1,0]
            S1plot[Aloop,Bloop] = soln[len(time)-1,1]
            KS0plot[Aloop,Bloop] = soln[len(time)-1,2]
            PS1plot[Aloop,Bloop] = soln[len(time)-1,3]
            Kplot[Aloop,Bloop] = soln[len(time)-1,4]
            Pplot[Aloop,Bloop] = soln[len(time)-1,5]

            Stot = S0plot + S1plot + KS0plot + PS1plot  
    Stot = f(y)
    print(Stot)
```

I'm missing something basic here. The code runs in less than a second, but outputs nothing!

Comment: None of the code after `return ydot[:,0]` runs...

Comment: Nothing changes when I remove `return ydot[:,0]` and add `return Stot` below the line where `Stot` is defined...

Comment: The execution of the code changes significantly. `f(y)` doesn't immediately return during the very first for loop. And returning after that line won't print it either because calling `return` **exits** the function to where you called it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have the modules that are required for import, so I can't test the code and I don't want to make stumps for them.  However, it seems that your indentation levels (i.e. scope) is off. You have `def f(y)` at the top, global level (no indentation), but you are trying to both call and print it at indention level 1. This means that you are attempting to call the function from within itself and then print the results. Your function doesn't appear to be recursive so I don't think this is what you want.

Try removing the indentation from your last two lines.